# Why is there a small pump on the cold line above my water heater?

Tags: water, heater, pump

Can someone help me understand what I’m looking at and how it works?

Between the expansion tank and my water heater is a T that goes to a Y strainer then a small pump and valve. That line runs upstairs and I can’t seem to trace it beyond that without destroying anything. The pump is AC powered and has been unplugged for years. The valve has been open.

Oddly, the arrow on the pumps fitting points towards the heater.

I don’t understand where this third line would go, what function it serves, and where to reconnect it given I have to move where it goes upstairs into a wall.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Usually the pump in hot water system are used to deliver instant hot water at any faucet by constantly recycling it. Instant means when opening a faucet you do not have to wait for a  while before hot water arrives.

Comment: Thank you  I didn’t know this was a feature at all. Maybe now that it’s plugged in, we can get some benefit out of it!

Answer (score 2):

Ah ha!

This is a very common system that accomplishes two things: gets hot water coming out of the faucet much quicker and saves tons of water so you’re not sitting there wasting cold water waiting for it to get hot.

The pump connects to the fixture furthest from the heater and keeps water pumping through until hot water is returning to the heater. That way the lines are always full with hot water.

More on that here:

https://youtu.be/dPHtFe_4nSQ

And

https://youtu.be/AQC_shrv8KA

Comment: And given the total lack of insulation on the recirculating loop in your pictures, you can expect to pay a LOT more for your water heater keeping that loop hot all the time (and extra air-conditioning in the summer, too.) But if you like the math of spending $50/month on heat to save $1/month in water, enjoy. Without completely and carefully insulating all the supply lines and the return line, they are a large expense to run.

Comment: ^^^ what he said, probably why it was left unplugged

Comment: Somebody must be paying a lot for there gas or using an electric heater. I have had this for many years and I have months where the gas bill is less then $50.00. My lines are insulated both in the walls and in the basement. I actually route the hot return through fin tubing to heat the basement in the winter, it works great.

Comment: @Gil , the fact that your lines are insulated makes a Very Large Difference in how much this costs to run. We can see this part is utterly uninsulated, I'll infer that the rest of it isn't, either.